# How to convert Point Coordinate in Database to Point struct GoLang

Tags: go

```
CurrentCoordinates  []uint8 `json:"current_coordinates"`
```

```
type Points struct {
    Lat     float64    `json:"lat"`
    Lng     float64    `json:"lng"`
}
```

DB Column has data as :
POINT(6.887035 79.883757)

From DB i got it into []uint8, then the result is :
[0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 35 161 45 231 82 140 27 64 28 39 133 121 143 248 83 64]

Anyone know how to convert this to coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates are stored at the end of your slice, both have 8 bytes which are the little-endian encoded bytes of the [IEEE 754 double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) representation of the floating point numbers.

You may use the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package to get the floating-point data of the coordinates as an `uint64`, and you may use [`math.Float64frombits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64frombits) to "convert" that data to `float64` type.

This is how you can decode them:

```
data := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 35, 161, 45, 231, 82, 140, 27, 64, 28, 39, 133, 121, 143, 248, 83, 64}

d := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(data[9:])
x := math.Float64frombits(d)
d = binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(data[17:])
y := math.Float64frombits(d)

fmt.Println(x, y)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tfte5sdEbfQ)):

```
6.887035 79.883757
```

The beginning of your data may be SRID (spatial reference identifier) and/or some kind of distance / accuracy for searches, depends on the database you're using.

Alternatively you may create an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) reading from your slice using [`bytes.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader), and use the [`binary.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) function:

```
data := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 35, 161, 45, 231, 82, 140, 27, 64, 28, 39, 133, 121, 143, 248, 83, 64}

r := bytes.NewReader(data[9:])
var x, y float64
if err := binary.Read(r, binary.LittleEndian, &x); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := binary.Read(r, binary.LittleEndian, &y); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(x, y)
```

This will output the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3A65qEZddDE).